# Creating two dynamic file paths is gatsby-node

Tags: node.js, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

pardon me I'm a bit new to Gatsby and I'm still learning.

I have two different file paths for my markdown both located in the same path: content/blog and content/projects. I was hoping to use the file path difference to help navigate my routing, so that I could do : website.com/blog/post1 and website.com/project/project1. However, I'm not sure how to query the two paths so that they're different.

This is my gatsby-node file. I'm guessing that I have to specify the within graphql, but I don't even know how the path are loaded in.

I'm using the gatsby-starter-blog for reference
https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog

```
const path = require(`path`)
const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  // Define a template for blog post
  const blogPost = path.resolve(`./src/templates/blog-post.js`)

  // Get all markdown blog posts sorted by date
  const blogpost = await graphql(
    `
      {
        allMarkdownRemark(
          sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: ASC }
          limit: 1000
        ) {
          nodes {
            id
            fields {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )

  if (blogpost.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild(
      `There was an error loading your blog posts`,
      blogpost.errors
    )
    return
  }

  const posts = blogpost.data.allMarkdownRemark.nodes

  // Create blog posts pages
  // But only if there's at least one markdown file found at "content/blog" (defined in gatsby-config.js)
  // `context` is available in the template as a prop and as a variable in GraphQL

  if (posts.length > 0) {
    posts.forEach((post, index) => {
      const previousPostId = index === 0 ? null : posts[index - 1].id
      const nextPostId = index === posts.length - 1 ? null : posts[index + 1].id

      createPage({
        path: post.fields.slug,
        component: blogPost,
        context: {
          id: post.id,
          previousPostId,
          nextPostId,
        },
      })
    })
  }
}

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions

  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode, basePath: 'content/blog'})

    createNodeField({
      name: `slug`,
      node,
      value: `/blog${value}`,
    })
  }
}

exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions

  // Explicitly define the siteMetadata {} object
  // This way those will always be defined even if removed from gatsby-config.js

  // Also explicitly define the Markdown frontmatter
  // This way the "MarkdownRemark" queries will return `null` even when no
  // blog posts are stored inside "content/blog" instead of returning an error
  createTypes(`
    type SiteSiteMetadata {
      author: Author
      siteUrl: String
      social: Social
    }

    type Author {
      name: String
      summary: String
    }

    type Social {
      twitter: String
    }

    type MarkdownRemark implements Node {
      frontmatter: Frontmatter
      fields: Fields
    }

    type Frontmatter {
      title: String
      description: String
      date: Date @dateformat
    }

    type Fields {
      slug: String

    }
  `)
}
```

**Update**
So I found a work around, but I'm not a huge fan of this. I realize, I could create a subfield in my md file. I could work around doing this, but I feel like there might be a better way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

So what I understand is that you have the following directory structure:

`/content/blog/post1.md` - blog posts
`/content/project/prjoect1.md` - project pages

It's not clear how or what makes the two types of page different, only that perhaps the path is the signal.  I'm going to assume that you want 2 templates for each, i.e. `blog-post.js` and `project-page.js`.

I'm also going to assume that your `gatsby-config.js` simply sources from `/content/`, like this:

```js
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `markdown-pages`,
        path: `${__dirname}/content/`
      }
    },
```

With that assumption, what I think you want to do is vary the `component` field used in the `createPage` calls.

Using the Gatsby example code (with bits snipped out), it might look like this:

```js
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  // Define a template for BOTH blog post and project
  const directoryComponentMap = {
    'blog': path.resolve(`./src/templates/blog-post.js`),
    'project': path.resolve('./src/templates/project-page.js'),
  };
  // snip

  if (posts.length > 0) {
    posts.forEach((post, index) => {
      // snip
      
      // Very naive approach to get the containing directory
      const [_, dir] = post.fields.slug.split('/');  
      

      createPage({
        path: post.fields.slug,
        // Select the component to render the page here
        component: directoryComponentMap[dir],  
        context: {
          id: post.id,
          previousPostId,
          nextPostId
        }
      })
    })
  }
}
```

I created an example in [this Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-cdn-9kxuhz?file=/gatsby-node.js).

The blog post is here: https://9kxuhz.sse.codesandbox.io/blog/post1/
The project page is here: https://9kxuhz.sse.codesandbox.io/project/project1/

There's no listing page, just the bare minimum.

Personally, I'd advise not relying on the parent directory as it's not very scalable as you scale to more page types and, probably, different directory structures.

I'd go for a frontmatter field, like:

```
---
template: project
#snip
---
A project page
```

And use the `frontmatter.template` field to switch on.